# CPLEX How to use the set in tuple as index

Tags: algorithm, tuples, scheduling, cplex, opl

I want make a flexible job shop scheduling problem with MIP.

Here is my example. There is 2 Jobs and 3 Machines. Job 1 has 2 operations O11 and O12, and Job 2 has 3 operations O21, O22, and O23. Each operations can choose one of its available machines in the first set, and its processing time is the second set.

For example, `<2,3,{1,3},{7,9}>` implies O23(the third operation of Job 2) can perform on machine 1 and machine 3 with processing time 7 and 9.

Because each operation can only choose a machine, so the constraint I want to make is like `forall(i, j) sum(k in mch_set) x[<i,j>][k]==1;`

ex. `X[<2,3>][1]+X[<2,3>][3]==1`or `X[2][3][1]+X[2][3][3]==1`

Here is my code I wrote, but there are some problems I don't know how to solve.

```
int nbJobs = 2;
int nbMchs = 3;

range Jobs = 1..nbJobs;
range Mchs = 1..nbMchs; 

// tuple
tuple operationInfo{
    int jobID;
    int pos; // j-th operation of job i
    {int} mch_set; // candidate machine ID for this job
    {int} pt_set;
};


{operationInfo} OpsInfo ={
<1,1,{1,2},{3,5}>,
<1,2,{1,2,3},{10,5,8}>,
<2,1,{2},{4}>,
<2,2,{1,3},{8,5}>,
<2,3,{2,3},{7,9}>
};

// Number of operations in each job
int nbOps[i in Jobs] = max(o in OpsInfo: o.jobID==i) o.pos;

dvar boolean x[o in ops][k in o.mchs_set];

subject to
{
    forall(o in OpsInfo)
      sum(k in o.mchs_set) x[o][k]==1;
};
```

I clearly don't know how to formulate Xijk because for each job i, j and k will change.
Is there any better method for me to formulate this problem?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix would be to define `x` like this:

```
int maxOps = max(i in Jobs) nbOps[i];
dvar boolean x[o in ops][1..maxOps];
```

With this definition you have defined more variables than you need but you are free to use only the ones that you need. In order to avoid "variable unused" warnings, you can add a simple constraint like

```
forall(o in OpsInfo)
  forall(k in 1..maxOps)
    if (!(k in o.mchs_set))
      x[o][k] == 0;
```

Comment: So I can't use dynamic 2D array with different size in CPLEX IDE.If I use docplex in python, can I use the dynamic array in python?

Comment: Yes, in Python the second dimension of an array can vary with the first.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. As an expert in CPLEX like you, would you recommend to use CPLEX python API rather than CPLEX IDE? It seems that there are more constraints on building data structures using CPLEX IDE.

Comment: I don't think you need to switch to Python. You just have to think in more flexible ways. I think you ask the same or at least very similar questions in different places and already got multiple ideas how to model things. The best option is to create all valid combinations of i, j, k as a tuple set and then use a one-dimensional decision variable that is indexed by these tuples.